# cakephp crud plugin return validation errors

Tags: rest, cakephp, crud, cakephp-3.7

When PATCHing to a record using the [Crud plugin](https://crud.readthedocs.io/) and `Crud.Api` listener, a successful PATCH returns a `200 OK` with an empty data array in the response.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": []
}
```

When validation fails after a PATCH, a `422 Unprocessable Entity` with the following response is returned:

```
{
    "message": "A validation error occurred",
    "url": "\/admin\/users\/edit\/4.json",
    "code": 422,
    "file": "\/app\/vendor\/friendsofcake\/crud\/src\/Listener\/ApiListener.php",
    "line": 189
}
```

but I expected something like:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "data": [
       "errors": [...]
    ]
    
}
```

> https://crud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/listeners/api.html#http-put-edit
>
> If success is false a HTTP response code of 422 will be returned,
> along with a list of validation errors from the model in the data
> property of the response body.

Does the plugin need to be configured to return the errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not overly familiar with the Crud plugin, but that response looks like the default CakePHP exception renderer response, so I'd guess that you probably haven't configured your app to use the Crud exception renderer:

**config/app.php**

```
'Error' => [
    'exceptionRenderer' => \Crud\Error\ExceptionRenderer::class,
    // ...
],
```

Quote from the docs:

> Note: However if you are using CakePHP 3.3+’s PSR7 middleware feature the exceptionRenderer config won’t be used and instead you will have to set the Error.exceptionRenderer config in config/app.php to 'Crud\Error\ExceptionRenderer' as following

See **[Crud Docs > Listeners > API > Exception handler](https://crud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/listeners/api.html#exception-handler)**